# Can't boot linux from SSD, after switched for windows on other HDD

Tags: linux, boot, uefi

I changed my disk from SSD (where I have linux OS) to HDD (where is windwos 8 installed), which I haven't used for a while, after I done what I needed to do, I switched disks back (connected back SSD with linux debian) and I am not able to boot it again, here is an error I Get [image]

Comment: check the boot settings in bios

Comment: If UEFI, system forgets boot entries for an unplugged drive. Often UEFI will find Windows, but not any Linux systems. Can you boot the fallback or hard drive entry from UEFI boot menu? If not UEFI is system set for BIOS/CSM/Legacy boot? You may need to recreate UEFI entry or reinstall grub if UEFI or BIOS. May be best to see details, use ppa version with live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report, do not post report, do not use auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @oldfred for some reason I wasn't able to launch boot repair, I work it out by reinstalling GRUb with help of this tutorial https://www.debian.wayoflinux.com/installing/post-install/fix-common-issues/reinstall-grub, if you paste it as an answer I will accept it, thx

Comment: @oldfred you might prefer to understand clearly instead of guessing what goes on, see http://rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/principles.html if *my* guess is correct :-) (your advice reads a bit like "village magic" typical for ubuntu forums to me, and the situation is pretty straightforward *if* those principles are understood)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit is that UEFI depends on in-computer NVRAM storing boot configuration you can read or modify through `efibootmgr` utility; Windows tends to install a "fallback bootloader" aptly specified by MSFT in UEFI spec as `\EFI\BOOT\bootx64.efi` (`bootia32.efi` for 32-bit x86), so it booted first time through this fallback and most probably "fixed" the NVRAM configuration later (I'm no expert on Windows so it's a word of mouth for me and not experience).
So you could either:

1. "fix" NVRAM after Windows' "fix" (by running `grub-install` having booted from UEFI-capable rescue media *in UEFI mode*), or
2. put a copy of `/boot/efi/grubx64.efi` into `/boot/efi/bootx64.efi` (but this might break after grub version update).

There are more exotic ways (like using [refind boot iso](http://rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) to chainload the main bootloader) but I'd rather suggest reading up on [EFI bootloading principles](http://rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/principles.html) if you want to understand what goes on and what (and why) can be done -- apparently @oldfred has pointed you in the right direction (but might benefit from the same manual as well) so hope he remakes the hint into an answer :-)

Just in case you'll need those tools again, my [ALT Rescue](http://en.altlinux.org/rescue) image has both refind, efibootmgr, grub, etc handy.

Answer (score 3):

UEFI systems forget boot entries for an unplugged drive. Often UEFI will find Windows and create new UEFI entry, but not most Linux systems. They should also let you boot the fallback or hard drive entry that is identical to the way external drives (installer) are booted. Grub now installs /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi as fallback. With old versions we had to manually create that entry & Boot-Repair has done that as another fix also.

Can you boot the fallback or hard drive entry from UEFI boot menu? 
If not UEFI is system set for BIOS/CSM/Legacy boot?

UEFI entries require the GUID of the ESP - efi system partition to know where to look for boot files.
You may need to recreate UEFI entry or reinstall grub if UEFI or BIOS. May be best to see details, use ppa version with live installer (2nd option) or any working install, not older Boot-Repair ISO: Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report, do not post report, do not use auto fix till reviewed.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

You only need to use efibootmgr to restore a correct UEFI boot entry. Many just do a total reinstall of grub which uses efibootmgr to add new entry as default boot in UEFI NVRAM. Example efibootmgr entry:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/668506/changed-the-uefi-motherboard-on-a-dell-laptop-now-it-says-no-os-detected

```
man efibootmgr
```